# How can I make a child object aware of the property name to which it is assigned on its parent?

Tags: c#

**UPDATE:** since inquiring minds want to know, here's some context as to why I'm needing to do what I'm doing:

My C# application (app A) interfaces with another application (app B, which is not mine) that sends me a Parent Id, a path to navigate to within the Parent's object graph, and a value to set once it gets there. App B has no notion of the Ids of the nested objects within the Parent model in the C# app, it has no notion that there is more than one instance of a Parent; it's job is simply to accept low level requests from external devices and turn them into something a little higher level and hand them to app A. Each Child object in a Parent has a unique path- no two references will point to the same Child object. So B might send A something that looks like the following JSON object:

```
{
    'Id'   : 12345,
    'Path' : 'ChildProperty.NestedChildProperty.AnotherNestedChildProperty',
    'Value': 'Ligers are bred for their skills in magic.'
}
```

There are other options to solve this issue, such as navigating up from a leaf Child object or down from the Parent object, but those are far less efficient, both in terms of database queries and application processing, than being able to query a repository of Children by the Id of the parent they belong to and their path within the Parent's object graph.

The example below is barebones. It doesn't even illustrated nested Child objects. It is as small as possible to illustrate the problem presented in the question without the context provided up to this point.

So with that...

---

Let's say I have a couple of classes like so:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child ChildProperty {get; set;}
}

public class Child 
{
    public string ParentPropertyName {get; protected set;}
}
```

It is worth noting that a Child will never be referenced by more than one Parent for this model. What I want to do is make the `Child` instance aware of the property name it is being assigned to, so with this call:

```
parent.ChildProperty = new Child();
```

I have

```
parent.ChildProperty.ParentPropertyName == "ChildProperty" //evaluates to true
```

I've been down some weird rabbit holes trying to use some combination of events and Expressions/MemberExpressions and factories and reflection and recursive graph traversal to try to make this work, but nothing does, simply for the fact that assignment to the Parent property is done after instantiation of the Child. Doing this manually on the child like so:

```
parent.ChildProperty = new Child("ChildProperty");
```

is not an option as it is too prone to error.

The best I've been able to come up with is a sort of middle ground that looks more or less like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    private Child childProperty;

    public Child ChildProperty
    {
        get { return childProperty; }
        set
        {
            childProperty = value;
            if (childProperty.ParentPropertyName == null)
            {
                childProperty.SetParentPropertyName(() => this.ChildProperty);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public string ParentPropertyName { get; protected set; }

    internal void SetParentPropertyName(Expression<Func<object>> exp)
    {
        this.ParentPropertyName = (((MemberExpression) (exp.Body)).Member).Name;
    }
}
```

While this works and is a lot better than manually passing in a string, the real classes are more complicated with wider & deeper object graphs, and thus I'd have to copy that setter logic on every property on every class where it was needed. On top of that, it transfers a functionality to the `Parent` that really belongs to the `Child`.

So that brings me back to my question- is there a way to make the `Child` instance aware of the property name on the `Parent` to which it is being assigned without intervention from the `Parent` instance?

Comment: Just one question... **Why?**

Comment: If you need to know where an object has been assigned then you have a problem in your design. One good way to think about why this wouldn't work is that an object could be assigned in multiple locations.

Comment: I figured the question of "Why?" would come up. It would take more than a comment to explain why we made the decisions we made. With two tiny classes and no context it seems like bad design- I realize that. We went through a LOT of options before we landed on this, and for our model, it makes a lot of sense. Luckily, this isn't an architecture discussion, so hopefully we can stick to the narrow scope of the problem at hand.

Comment: @joelmdev - See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels.  It's very *likely* that if you give us context, we can help find a better solution, but if you're certain that you need this specific functionality... well, sometimes you *do* need square wheels.

Comment: @Bobson when your track looks like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IoYQaiKfayU a square wheel works quite well.

Comment: "it transfers a functionality to the Parent that really belongs to the Child." I disagree with that statement (IMO it belongs to the parent), and so does the C# language as it seems. That may be why you are having so much trouble. Alternative: Maybe you can create a "Container<T> class (or struct)" which is similar to `Nullable<T>`. In your parent class, you use properties of this class instead of normal properties. The constructor of `Container<T>` takes a name as argument, and when its value is assigned, it copies its name to the value.

Comment: @joelmdev - And that's why I said sometimes you do need them.  I'm testing an answer now, but it would help if you can provide feedback on Sriram's just-posted answer's questions.

Comment: @Bobson I will edit to give some context. Please be patient. Hopefully we can dike the flow of comments in the meantime.

Comment: @joelmdev - Alright, answer posted.  I hope it helps.

Comment: @Bobson context provided. Please let me know if the track upon which my square wheel is rolling is sufficiently semi-circular.

Comment: @joelmdev - Interesting.  I can also see solutions involving a recursive dictionary, so you could access it by `Data["ChildProperty"]["NestedChildProperty"]["AnotherNestedChildProperty"].Value`.  I'll write up an example of that, in case you don't like the Reflection answer.  But it is an interesting problem.

Comment: @Chris http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254341/a-car-with-square-wheels#254353

Comment: @joelmdev - Alright, second answer posted.  Hopefully one of the two will work for you.

Comment: @joelmdev: That can be countered by such as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/why-do-people-question-every-question or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122307/stricter-rules-on-irrelevant-answers (the classic "Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle" question). I should have stated it more subjectively though possibly but without any further context its impossible to tell the difference between somebody such as you who has spent a long time considering the design and somebody just starting who just doesn't realise he's following a potentially bad path. Good luck though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve it reliably. Not because of technical reason, but because of logical.

Assume you have:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child ChildProperty {get; set;}
    public Child ChildProperty2 {get; set;}
}

public class Child 
{
    public string ParentPropertyName {get; protected set;}
}

var child = new Child();
parent.ChildProperty = child;
parent.ChildProperty2 = child;
```

Now what do expect `child.ParentPropertyName` name to be? `ChildProperty` or `ChildProperty2`?

Question as stands doesn't makes sense. It will be easy to answer if you can explain what is the intent.

Comment: I failed to mention that a Child will never be referenced by more than one parent for this model. I have edited the question to reflect this, and I will edit it further to give more context shortly.

Answer (score 1):

With the extra context, I'm going to provide a completely separate answer which addresses it in an entirely different manner.

What you're given appears to be a flattened tree.  That is, each node knows its own path, not just it's parent.  You can convert that back to a tree when you make objects from it.  Here's a `Data` class which acts instead of both `Parent` and `Child`.

```
class Data
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Data> Children { get; set; }

    public Data()
    {
        Children = new Dictionary<string, Data>();
    }
    public Data(int Id, string value) : this()
    {
        this.ID = Id;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public Data this[string name]
    {
        get { 
            if (Children.ContainsKey(name)) return Children[name];
            else {
                Children.Add(name, new Data());
                return Children[name];
            }
        }
        set {
            if (Children.ContainsKey(name)) Children[name] = value;
            else Children.Add(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = new Data();
data["ChildProperty"]["NestedChildProperty"]["AnotherNestedChildProperty"] = 
       new Data(12345, "Ligers are bred for their skills in magic.");
Console.WriteLine(data["ChildProperty"]["NestedChildProperty"]["AnotherNestedChildProperty"].Value);
```

It's up to you how to parse the `Path` into it's discrete parts.

Note that this version doesn't provide a mechanism from going from a child up to its Parent, but it's easy enough to add a `public Data(Data parent)` constructor instead of the empty one, and a property to store it.

Comment: This is a neat solution, and I've upvoted it as such, but I don't think it'll work for us and ultimately it doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: @joelmdev - How about the other one?

Comment: The other one is very similar to something we already tried that didn't work as well as the example code in the question. Unfortunately all of the answers here offer alternatives but none directly address the question at hand, though at this point I think the answer to the question is, "You can't."

Comment: @joelmdev - It does seem that way.  I don't quite  understand *why* none of these work, but I will accept that they don't.  One last suggestion, although I'm not going to try and code it: Have you considered reversing the tree?  Specifically, have a `Child` object that contains a `Parent`, and multiple `Child`s can each have the same `Parent`.  Rather than `Parent`->`Child`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really understand this

```
parent.ChildProperty.ParentPropertyName == "ChildProperty"
```

Perhaps you simply need

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child {get; set;}
}

public class Child 
{
    public Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```

So that they can find each other. Add that text property for whatever reason, so you can do

```
parent.Child.WhateverProperty == "WhateverProperty"
```

---

> So that brings me back to my question- is there a way to make the Child instance aware of the property name on the Parent to which it is being assigned without intervention from the Parent instance?

They must know about each other (so that my guess is somewhat right). And then:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child Child {get; set;}
    public string WhateverProperty {get; set;}
}

public class Child 
{
    public Parent Parent {get; set;}
    public string WhateverProperty
    {
        get { return Parent.WhateverProperty; }
        set { Parent.WhateverProperty = value; }
    }
}
```

If parent is missing, then you can return `"Something"`.

Comment: If you don't understand it then ask for clarification in a comment. I believe the question is to do with trying to assign the identity to both elements whenever one is changed

Comment: The first line is just to illustrate what the property value is set to.

Answer (score 0):

I still want to know why you want to do this, but Reflection is your answer.  There are two steps to this:

First, the `Child` has to know what `Parent` to look at.  This can be accomplished in one of two ways.  Second, the `Child` has to know how to get the name from the `Parent` - this is pretty straight forward.

To address the second part first, add this function to the `Child` object:

```
private static string GetParentPropertyName(Parent parent, Child child)
{
    var matches = parent.GetType().GetProperties()
                        .Where(x => x.GetValue(parent, null) == child);
    return matches.Single().Name;
}
```

This will check all properties on the specified `Parent` to find the one that's storing the specified `Child`.  Then it will return the `Name` of that property.  Note that as written, this will throw an exception if there is not **exactly one** property holding the `Child`.  Adjust as appropriate to your scenario.

For the first part, there's two ways you can call this function.  Which is best depends on your usage.

1. If you're going to guarantee a 1:1 relationship, then the best way is to pass the `Parent` to the `Child` when it's created.  Your `Child` object will look like this:

   ```
   public class Child
   {
       private Parent _parent;

       public Child(Parent parent)
       {
           _parent = parent;
       }

       public string ParentPropertyName { 
           get { return GetParentPropertyName(_parent, this); } 
       }
   }
   ```

   I'd suggest automatically creating the `Child` when `Parent.Child` is first accessed or when `Parent` is first created.
2. If you don't want to guarantee that relationship, add the following function to your `Child` instead of having the `ParentPropertyName` property:

   ```
   public string GetParentPropertyName(Parent parent) 
   { 
      return GetParentPropertyName(parent, this); 
   }
   ```

   You can then add a function or property to the `Parent` which does

   ```
   return this.Child.GetParentPropertyName(this);
   ```